# How can I make Perspective view resemble Orthographic view?

Tags: camera

everyone. I'm back.

[image]

I'm creating the torso of my game character,Tanya...and I was wondering how I can make Perspective View look like Orthographic View. I saw this teaser that Emil Macko created for FNaC2 that struck my fancy and to me it looks like Orthographic view. I want to implement this so I can properly model Tanya. Can someone please help me to replicate this camera setting?

[image]

If someone helps me,I'll give them a big thumbs up.

Comment: I meant that I wanted it to be the same as this camera setting above. I need this to properly model Tanya.

Answer (score 4):

Press NUMPAD-5 to switch between perspective and orthographic view in viewport. Go to the Camera settings in the properties window with the camera selected if you want to change your camera to be orthographic.